# What's wrong with my turtle release channel?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build IPA image for iOS with expo turtle-cli but I'm getting an error. I was trying to solve this for more then a day but the only meaningful message I saw was *"Experience \"@USER/PROJECT\" for platform \"ios\" and release channel \"testing\" was not published recently enough to be used on this client. The author will need to publish a new version."*. But it doesn't tell me a lot.

This is the command I'm running on my Azure pipeline

```
turtle build:ios --team-id ABCDEFGH --dist-p12-path ./certs/project_dist.p12 --provisioning-profile-path ./certs/project.mobileprovision --release-channel testing -o /Users/vsts/project.ipa
```

And this is the output

```
2019-08-27T12:41:17.6270040Z Aug 27 12:41:17 turtle[2320] WARN:  [33mThere is a new version of turtle-cli available (0.11.2).[39m
2019-08-27T12:41:17.6271940Z [33mYou are currently using turtle-cli 0.10.0[39m
2019-08-27T12:41:17.6273140Z [33mRun `npm install -g turtle-cli` to get the latest version[39m
2019-08-27T12:41:17.6274780Z [33m  platform: "ios"[39m
2019-08-27T12:41:20.4992540Z Aug 27 12:41:20 turtle[2320] INFO:  [32mshell app for SDK 34.0.0 doesn't exist, downloading...[39m
2019-08-27T12:41:20.4993660Z [32m  platform: "ios"[39m
2019-08-27T12:41:20.4994460Z [32m  buildPhase: "setting up environment"[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:01.0037950Z Aug 27 12:42:01 turtle[2320] INFO:  [32mshell app has been downloaded[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:01.0069850Z [32m  platform: "ios"[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:01.0107610Z [32m  buildPhase: "setting up environment"[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:01.0113250Z Aug 27 12:42:01 turtle[2320] INFO:  [32mextracting shell app (this may take a while)...[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:01.0114460Z [32m  platform: "ios"[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:01.0115630Z [32m  buildPhase: "setting up environment"[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:46.8717050Z Aug 27 12:42:46 turtle[2320] INFO:  [32mshell app extracted[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:46.8718270Z [32m  platform: "ios"[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:46.8719260Z [32m  buildPhase: "setting up environment"[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8056230Z Aug 27 12:42:49 turtle[2320] ERROR: [31m{ StatusCodeError: 400 - "Experience \"@USER/PROJECT\" for platform \"ios\" and release channel \"testing\" was not published recently enough to be used on this client. The author will need to publish a new version."[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8057780Z [31m    at new StatusCodeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8058780Z [31m    at Request.plumbing.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8059900Z [31m    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8060930Z [31m    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8062490Z [31m    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8063300Z [31m    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8064050Z [31m    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8064800Z [31m    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8065530Z [31m    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8066330Z [31m    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8067080Z [31m    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8067740Z [31m    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8068880Z [31m    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8069630Z [31m    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8070610Z [31m    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8071420Z [31m  name: 'StatusCodeError',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8072050Z [31m  statusCode: 400,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8072730Z [31m  message:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8073640Z [31m   '400 - "Experience \\"@USER/PROJECT\\" for platform \\"ios\\" and release channel \\"testing\\" was not published recently enough to be used on this client. The author will need to publish a new version."',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8074410Z [31m  error:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8075290Z [31m   'Experience "@USER/PROJECT" for platform "ios" and release channel "testing" was not published recently enough to be used on this client. The author will need to publish a new version.',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8075990Z [31m  options:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8076700Z [31m   { resolveWithFullResponse: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8077430Z [31m     url: 'https://exp.host:443/@USER/PROJECT',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8078130Z [31m     headers:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8079030Z [31m      { 'Exponent-SDK-Version': '34.0.0',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8079710Z [31m        'Exponent-Platform': 'ios',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8080440Z [31m        'Expo-Release-Channel': 'testing',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8081170Z [31m        Accept: 'application/expo+json,application/json' },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8081890Z [31m     callback: [Function: RP$callback],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8082870Z [31m     transform: undefined,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8083890Z [31m     simple: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8084640Z [31m     transform2xxOnly: false },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8085320Z [31m  response:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8086000Z [31m   IncomingMessage {[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8086830Z [31m     _readableState:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8087590Z [31m      ReadableState {[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8088240Z [31m        objectMode: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8088890Z [31m        highWaterMark: 16384,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8089690Z [31m        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8090440Z [31m        length: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8091170Z [31m        pipes: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8091860Z [31m        pipesCount: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8092500Z [31m        flowing: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8093130Z [31m        ended: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8093750Z [31m        endEmitted: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8094670Z [31m        reading: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8095360Z [31m        sync: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8096100Z [31m        needReadable: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8096840Z [31m        emittedReadable: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8097550Z [31m        readableListening: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8098240Z [31m        resumeScheduled: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8098970Z [31m        paused: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8100290Z [31m        emitClose: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8101040Z [31m        autoDestroy: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8101730Z [31m        destroyed: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8102470Z [31m        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8103240Z [31m        awaitDrain: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8104150Z [31m        readingMore: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8104840Z [31m        decoder: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8105580Z [31m        encoding: null },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8106320Z [31m     readable: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8107060Z [31m     domain: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8107720Z [31m     _events:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8108480Z [31m      [Object: null prototype] {[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8109280Z [31m        end: [Array],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8110000Z [31m        close: [Array],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8110990Z [31m        data: [Function],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8111650Z [31m        error: [Function] },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8112400Z [31m     _eventsCount: 4,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8113140Z [31m     _maxListeners: undefined,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8114080Z [31m     socket:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8114950Z [31m      TLSSocket {[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8115700Z [31m        _tlsOptions: [Object],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8116450Z [31m        _secureEstablished: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8117130Z [31m        _securePending: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8117890Z [31m        _newSessionPending: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8118640Z [31m        _controlReleased: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8119340Z [31m        _SNICallback: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8120040Z [31m        servername: 'exp.host',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8120670Z [31m        alpnProtocol: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8121410Z [31m        authorized: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8122160Z [31m        authorizationError: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8123150Z [31m        encrypted: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8123880Z [31m        _events: [Object],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8124700Z [31m        _eventsCount: 8,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8125490Z [31m        connecting: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8126220Z [31m        _hadError: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8126890Z [31m        _handle: [TLSWrap],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8127650Z [31m        _parent: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8128390Z [31m        _host: 'exp.host',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8129150Z [31m        _readableState: [ReadableState],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8129840Z [31m        readable: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8130590Z [31m        domain: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8131340Z [31m        _maxListeners: undefined,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8132100Z [31m        _writableState: [WritableState],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8132780Z [31m        writable: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8133830Z [31m        allowHalfOpen: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8134700Z [31m        _sockname: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8135480Z [31m        _pendingData: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8136180Z [31m        _pendingEncoding: '',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8136910Z [31m        server: undefined,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8137640Z [31m        _server: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8138370Z [31m        ssl: [TLSWrap],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8139050Z [31m        _requestCert: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8139800Z [31m        _rejectUnauthorized: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8140540Z [31m        parser: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8141290Z [31m        _httpMessage: [ClientRequest],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8142050Z [31m        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8142740Z [31m        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 632534,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8143820Z [31m        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8144720Z [31m        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8145490Z [31m        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8146190Z [31m        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8147470Z [31m        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8148220Z [31m     connection:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8148940Z [31m      TLSSocket {[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8149620Z [31m        _tlsOptions: [Object],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8150380Z [31m        _secureEstablished: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8151080Z [31m        _securePending: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8151830Z [31m        _newSessionPending: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8152530Z [31m        _controlReleased: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8153260Z [31m        _SNICallback: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8154100Z [31m        servername: 'exp.host',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8154960Z [31m        alpnProtocol: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8155700Z [31m        authorized: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8156390Z [31m        authorizationError: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8157430Z [31m        encrypted: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8158190Z [31m        _events: [Object],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8158940Z [31m        _eventsCount: 8,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8159620Z [31m        connecting: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8160390Z [31m        _hadError: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8161140Z [31m        _handle: [TLSWrap],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8161880Z [31m        _parent: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8162570Z [31m        _host: 'exp.host',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8163330Z [31m        _readableState: [ReadableState],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8164250Z [31m        readable: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8165000Z [31m        domain: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8165690Z [31m        _maxListeners: undefined,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8166450Z [31m        _writableState: [WritableState],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8167190Z [31m        writable: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8167930Z [31m        allowHalfOpen: false,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8168620Z [31m        _sockname: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8169380Z [31m        _pendingData: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8170130Z [31m        _pendingEncoding: '',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8170870Z [31m        server: undefined,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8171550Z [31m        _server: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8172290Z [31m        ssl: [TLSWrap],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8172980Z [31m        _requestCert: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8173690Z [31m        _rejectUnauthorized: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8174370Z [31m        parser: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8175140Z [31m        _httpMessage: [ClientRequest],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8175920Z [31m        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8176690Z [31m        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 632534,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8177450Z [31m        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8178150Z [31m        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8178890Z [31m        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8179660Z [31m        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8180430Z [31m        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8181130Z [31m     httpVersionMajor: 1,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8181870Z [31m     httpVersionMinor: 1,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8182610Z [31m     httpVersion: '1.1',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8183360Z [31m     complete: true,[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8184040Z [31m     headers:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8184790Z [31m      { server: 'nginx/1.13.12',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8185550Z [31m        date: 'Tue, 27 Aug 2019 12:42:49 GMT',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8186330Z [31m        'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8187030Z [31m        'content-length': '193',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8187790Z [31m        connection: 'close',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8188560Z [31m        'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800' },[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8189310Z [31m     rawHeaders:[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8190050Z [31m      [ 'Server',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8190730Z [31m        'nginx/1.13.12',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8191970Z [31m        'Date',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:49.8192750Z [31m        'Tue, 27 Aug 2019 12:42:49 GMT',[39m
2019-08-27T12:42:50.6641830Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need it anymore, but as the error says it looks like you haven't published your project recently and therefore it can't be used. In case someone else has the same problem open a terminal, get to your project directory and run:

```
expo publish
```

You can also read about publishing in the official documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/publishing/).

Comment: the whole point of using turtle CI is not to publish to expo servers but instead use your own build pipeline and build hosting. Otherwise you may just use eas build.